# Replicate only some tables of MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I currently have a ready-made structure cluster with MariaDB Galera with two servers that keeps both updated database. However I now have the need to create a new similar structure but with one difference, keeping only a few tables updated in the other server (which will be master also put to another application access).

- How can I do that?
- Can I Keep two masters but with partial synchronization?
- Do I have to use another tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of your topics:

- You can't do that with cluster replication.
- Multi-master is a cluster feature.
- You should try to use the [`replicate_wild_do_table`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#replicate_wild_do_table) setting.

Slave threads will be restricted to replicating tables that match the specified wildcard pattern. For example `replicate-wild-do-table=foo%.bar%` will replicate only updates to tables in all databases that start with foo and whose table names start with `bar`.

Comment: I tested and worked perfectly. Thank you very much, helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help out.

Comment: These replication options (`replicate_do_db`, `replicate_do_table`, `replicate_ignore_db`, `replicate_ignore_table`, `replicate_wild_do_table` and `replicate_wild_ignore_table`) work only with the master-slave replication MariaDB own and not with the Galera (this link explains better [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/)). So @ozzie come with a question: With this Galera limitation is not risky to master-slave with the MariaDB own? Because I've seen some people comment that this option is not very reliable, or even safe.

Comment: The documentation you kindly point out states "Within Galera cluster, replication filters should be used with caution.". I went further and wrote above that you couldn't do it with cluster replication. Exactly because it's unsafe. So, if you're planning to use replication filters, consider seting up a plain master/slave architecture, without galera.